# getPastEvents recursive loop

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

Consider there are 30000 events in a contract.

getPastEvents() method returns max 10000 results and if something goes above 10000 it throws error. Is there any recursive option where we can loop and track the 10000 results. When it comes to 10000 it restarts from that last block number and fetch another 10000.

First loop 10k, second loop 10K, and third loop 10k without any error summing up 30k.

Comment: What programming language are you using? Which library?

Comment: web3.js,  As mentioned in Tags web3.js

Comment: In the future, it's helpful to re-iterate that in the body. You'd be surprised by how many people miss tag their questions!